# Gaussian Mixture Model of Different Variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

The multiplication of two independent univariate Gaussian pdfs of variables $x$ and $y$ is equivalent to a multivariate Gaussian of the two variables (with diagonal covariance matrix).

Does the mixture of two such distributions, e.g.

$$
f(x,y) = \alpha \mathcal{N}(x;\mu_1, \sigma_1^2) + \beta \mathcal{N}(y;\mu_2, \sigma_2^2),
$$

also form a valid multivariate distribution (probably multimodal)? How can this be interpreted, or is this totally nonsensical?

Answer (score 0):

Makes no sense because:$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\alpha u(x)+\beta v(y)dxdy$$ cannot take value $1$ if $u$ and $v$ are PDF's.

E.g. have a look at term $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\alpha u(x)dxdy=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\alpha dy\in\{0,+\infty,-\infty\}$

Comment: even if $\alpha + \beta = 1$?

Comment: No, because there is a double integration.

Comment: You mean because the integration contains a constant which results in $-\infty$ or $\infty$ unless the weight is $0$. The double integral itself doesn't prove it can't sum to one, the double integral over a bi-variate Gaussian also sums to $1$.

Comment: Essential is that we are dealing with two *terms* of which one only depends on $x$ and the other only depends on $y$. That is not the case for bivariate Gaussian. Can you find me two pdf's $u,v$ together with constant $\alpha,\beta$ such that the integrand is indeed integrable and the result is not $0$?